# How do I create a projection file using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal, buffer

I am trying to obtain a buffer from a polyline file using GDAL with the following function

```
def createBuffer(inputfn, outputBufferfn, bufferDist):
    inputds = ogr.Open(inputfn)
    inputlyr = inputds.GetLayer()
    shpdriver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
    if os.path.exists(outputBufferfn):
        shpdriver.DeleteDataSource(outputBufferfn)
    outputBufferds = shpdriver.CreateDataSource(outputBufferfn)
    bufferlyr = outputBufferds.CreateLayer(outputBufferfn, geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
    featureDefn = bufferlyr.GetLayerDefn()
    for feature in inputlyr:
        ingeom = feature.GetGeometryRef()
        geomBuffer = ingeom.Buffer(bufferDist)
        outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
        outFeature.SetGeometry(geomBuffer)
        bufferlyr.CreateFeature(outFeature)
```

It works fine and creates the .bdf .shp .shx files

Well. But I would like to include in the same directory ( created by the function) the projectioin file .prj

I have got the following function.

```
def construye_proyeccion(nombre_arhivo):
    spatialRef = osr.SpatialReference()
    spatialRef.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
    spatialRef.MorphToESRI()
    file = open('%s.prj' % filename, 'w')
    file.write(spatialRef.ExportToWkt())
    file.close()
```

What can I do to create the buffer and his .prj file at the same time an in the same directory?

Comment: I believe that if you define the spatial reference system for your layer the shapefile driver would create .prj file automatically. Some not directly connected examples http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2012-November/034712.html

Answer (score 5):

You can combine the two functions I suppose that the projection of the two shapefiles are the same.

1) `spatialRef = inputlyr.GetSpatialRef()` gives you the projection of the original shapefile
2) `prj = os.path.splitext(outputBufferfn)[0] + ".prj"` gives you the name of the prj file of the buffer shapefile

```
outputBufferfn  = "a_shapefile.shp"
os.path.splitext(outputBufferfn)[0] + ".prj"
'a_shapefile.prj'
```

New

```
outputBufferfn  = "/users/shared/a_shapefile.shp"
(filepath, filename) = os.path.split(outputBufferfn)
os.path.join(filepath, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + ".prj")
'/users/shared/a_shapefile.prj'
```

Then:

```
def createBuffer(inputfn, outputBufferfn, bufferDist):
    ....
    # projection file
    spatialRef = inputlyr.GetSpatialRef()
    prj = os.path.splitext(outputBufferfn)[0] + ".prj"
    file = open(prj, 'w')
    file.write(spatialRef.ExportToWkt())
    file.close()
    ....
```

It is easiest and automatic (prj file)  with [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html) and [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) (another Python  wrapper of the GDAL/OGR library):

```
from shapely.geometry import shape, mapping 
import fiona
with fiona.open("a_shapefile.shp") as input:
    # change only the geometry of the shapefile schema to Polygon 
    input.schema['geometry'] = "Polygon"
    # write the buffer shapefile
    with fiona.open('buffer_a_shapefile.shp', 'w', 'ESRI Shapefile', input.schema , input.crs) as output:
       for feat in input:
           # GeoJSON to shapely geometry
           geom = shape(feat['geometry'])
           # shapely buffer to GeoJSON
           feat['geometry'] = mapping(geom.buffer(5))
           output.write(feat)
```

Some explications:

1) the schema of the original shapefile (`input.schema`, JSON/Python dictionary)

```
{'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'name', 'str:254')])}
```

2) the crs of the original shapefile

```
input.crs
{'init': u'epsg:4326'}
```

3) the schema of the buffered shapefile:

```
input.schema['geometry'] = "Polygon"
input.schema
{'geometry': 'Polygon', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'name', 'str:254')])}
```

Comment: Thanks It works but the .prj file is created in the script directory but the buffer into another directory named outputBufferfn. Then I have to move the .prj to the outputBufferfn directory. I can not find where I must change the route to obtain the four files together.

Comment: You must adapt the paths of your files.

Comment: look above ([os.path](http://pymotw.com/2/ospath/))

Comment: 3 years later... this is really helpful.  Thanks @gene !